# How to create anchor helper correctly in .net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to create a HtmlHelper to display links with the materialize framework icons.

I wrote this code because I could not find similar examples. My code works but it looks bad at least. I guess that I should use UrlHelper and UrlAction but i don't know how to do it.

```
public static IHtmlContent IconActionLink(this IHtmlHelper helper,
    string iconName,
    object iconHtmlAttributes,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    object linkHtmlAttributes)
{
    var content = new HtmlContentBuilder();
    var anchorStart = new TagBuilder("a");

    string routeValuesToString = "?";
    foreach(var r in new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues))
    {
        routeValuesToString += r.Key.ToString()+"="+r.Value.ToString()+"&";
    }
    routeValuesToString.Remove(routeValuesToString.Length-1);

    anchorStart.MergeAttribute("href", "../"+controllerName+"/"+actionName+"/"
        + routeValuesToString);

    anchorStart.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(linkHtmlAttributes));
    anchorStart.InnerHtml.Append(linkText);
    anchorStart.TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.StartTag;

    var icon = MaterialIcon(helper, iconName, iconHtmlAttributes);

    var anchorEnd = new TagBuilder("a") { TagRenderMode = TagRenderMode.EndTag };

    content.AppendHtml(anchorStart);
    content.AppendHtml(icon);
    content.AppendHtml(anchorEnd);

    return content;
}
```

I want to know how to properly insert RouteValues, Action, Controller to the tag.

Comment: By "archer" do you mean "anchor"? I'm not sure what an "archer helper" is.

Comment: I mean anchor. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a view, you can use `Url.Action()` to build a URL from route values, action, and controller, and use that in the `href` attribute.  To do that in an HTML helper, you need to construct your own URL helper.

```
// ASP.NET MVC
UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(
    helper.ViewContext.RequestContext,
    helper.RouteCollection);

// ASP.NET Core
UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(
    new ActionContext(
        helper.ViewContext.HttpContext,
        helper.ViewContext.RouteData,
        helper.ViewContext.ActionDescriptor));
```

Now, this section of code:

```
string routeValuesToString = "?";
foreach(var r in new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues))
{
    routeValuesToString += r.Key.ToString()+"="+r.Value.ToString()+"&";
}
routeValuesToString.Remove(routeValuesToString.Length-1);

anchorStart.MergeAttribute("href", "../"+controllerName+"/"+actionName+"/"
    + routeValuesToString);
```

Can be reduced to this:

```
anchorStart.MergeAttribute("href",
    urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues));
```

This will properly place values in the path when that's part of the route and place the rest in the query string.

---

**EDIT** -- I mentioned Tag Helpers and how they're composable.  Your HTML helper is doing a lot that's not related to the icon itself just to make it a link.  An HTML helper *could* take a rendering delegate but then you're still using your own HTML helper for the `a` tag.

Here's a simple *tag helper* for an `icon` tag that will give you a FontAwesome icon.

```
[HtmlTargetElement("icon", Attributes = "")]
public class IconTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("name")]
    public string IconName { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "span";

        string classAttribute = $@"fa fa-{IconName}";

        output.Attributes.Add("class", classAttribute);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use a normal `a` tag with the asp-* tag helper attributes and add any additional attributes (like data-id) to your `icon` tag.

```
<a asp-action="someAction" asp-controller="theController" asp-route-id="@Model.Id"><icon name="fa-thumbs-up" data-id="@Model.Id" /></a>
```

With `Model.Id == 1`, it'll render something like this:

```
<a href="/theController/someAction/1"><span class="fa fa-thumbs-up" data-id="1"></span></a>
```

In other words, the tag helper's only concern is how to turn your original `iconName` parameter into markup that represents an icon.  Everything else -- anchor tag construction, additional attributes, etc. -- can be left to other things that are more suited to those tasks.  It's a beautiful separation of concerns.

For this to work, you may need to refactor your `MaterialIcon` method, or even bring that code into the tag helper, depending on what it does.

Comment: I tried to do this but I get these errors:
'UrlHelper does' not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

'ViewContext' does not contain a definition for 'RequestContext' and no accessible extension method 'RequestContext' accepting a first argument of type 'ViewContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

'IHtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RouteCollection' and no accessible extension method 'RouteCollection' accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: You may have a mix of MVC and WebAPI namespaces imported or just the wrong one. They have type names that collide and have different constructor arguments. For example, [MVC's UrlHelper](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper) vs. [WebAPI's UrlHelper](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web.Http.Routing.UrlHelper).

Comment: Ah, I missed the asp.net-core tag. HTML helpers in ASP.NET Core are more for backward compatibility. Consider using Tag Helpers instead. They're composable and they allow you to write more natural-looking markup.

Comment: [Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro)

Comment: I'll try to update my answer in a bit for ASP.NET Core if I can.

Comment: I will try to create a helper tag, but I will be grateful if you can update your answer for .net core

Comment: anchorStart.MergeAttribute("href",urlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues)); throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: I tried looking for anything in `urlHelper.Action` that could throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` but found nothing. There's not much I can do without a stack track and who-knows-what else. You'll have to play around with it a bit yourself. Start by making sure you're getting the right overload of `Action`, and then try passing a minimal set of values in `routeValues` (or just pass `null`).  It worked for me with when I passed `new { id = 1 }` for the `routeValues` parameter in the view.